# Get the Method name where Property is accessed and read property value

Tags: postsharp

I would like to put PostSharp aspect attribute on one Property and know from which method property was accessed and what value it had at that time. Is that possible with PostSharp?

Example

```
static MyClass
{
[PostSharpAtrribute]
public string OutputFormat { get; set; }
}

public void Method1
{
MyClass.Instance.OutputFormat = "1";
}

public void Method2
{
MyClass.Instance.OutputFormat = "2";
}

public void Method3
{
MyClass.Instance.OutputFormat = "3";
}
```

PostSharp Aspect should read

```
Method "Method1" executed, property has value OutputFormat = 1
Method "Method2" executed, property has value OutputFormat = 2
Method "Method3" executed, property has value OutputFormat = 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the current value (before the change, you just use the Args.Value because the Set has not yet happened.

```
[Serializable] 
public class MyPropertyAspect: LocationInterceptionAspect 
{ 
    public override void OnSetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args) 
    { 
            object current = args.Value; //Set has not happened, remember this is an interception
            args.ProceedSetValue(); 

    }           
}
```

see http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-7-Interception-Aspects-e28093-Part-1.aspx and http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-8-Interception-Aspects-e28093-Part-2.aspx

To determine the caller you will need to traverse the callstack using StackTrace http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx

```
var st = new StackTrace();
st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name; //Might also be frame 2
```

or just put a trace aspect on your methods (which IMO would be better than reflecting the call stack) http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/Day-4-OnMethodBoundaryAspect.aspx

Comment: "Trace aspect on method" is what I need but how to share a data between aspects? To get method entries OnMethodBoundaryAspect will be used and to read property values the LocationInterceptionAspect aspect. So I will need to find out in LocationInterceptionAspect aspect what is the last entry was in OnMethodBoundaryAspect aspect.

Comment: For sharing data between aspects you need to build a complex aspect. See http://www.sharpcrafters.com/blog/post/PostSharp-Principals-Day-13-e28093-Aspect-Providers-e28093-Part-2.aspx for details on doing exactly what you want.